# CORS error when loading Fonts in production Rails/Vue app on Heroku and Amazon S3

Tags: heroku, vue.js, amazon-s3, cors, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a rails/VueJS app that is not loading my S3 svg files and fonts via font-awesome.  I have uploaded all files to my relative bucket folders in S3.  Any files uploaded via my app display correctly - however these static files and fonts are not working.  The CORS error is as follows:

error #1 (for fonts):

```
Access to font at 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/myappname/fonts/fontname-regular.woff' from origin 'https://nyappname.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

error #2 (for svg images):

```
GET https://s3.amazonaws.com/myappname/avatar-group.svg 404 (Not Found)
```

I assumed these are both caused by the same CORS setup issue, but I'm not sure.  I'm calling these files as follows in various places in my CSS files:

Custom.css

```
.avatar:after
{
    position: absolute;

    width: 0;
    height: 0;

    content: '';

    background-image: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/myappname/avatar-status.svg), url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/myappname/avatar-group.svg), url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/myappname/avatar-group-hover.svg), url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/myappname/avatar-group-hover-last.svg);
}
```

What should my CORS configuration in Amazon S3 be and should this configuration be setup on the root bucket only?  I've tried a hundred things to no avail, so any help would awesome...thx,

UPDATE:

Current CORS configuration in S3 bucket:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://myappname.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://myappname.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of trying different things, I realized it was a damn typo (one letter).  If it helps anyone having similar issues, I made progress by digging into the chrome console errors and clicking on the actual links/file names which showed me the error in the browser that my s3 "Bucket name does not exist".  This helped pinpoint the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I think `CORSRule`  only allow 1 `AllowedOrigin` per tag. You can change to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://myappname.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://myappname.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```